# Socket io integration issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, websocket

I am integrating Socket Io chat with in my website where i have 2 users admin and end no of user.I want to make communication between users to whom admin chooses from chat room. Now i am unable to connection and message functionality between admin to user and user to admin. In my app.js i have created instance required to server connection and then connected socket server to server with in defined port.Now i am trying to make interface for communication between user and admin. From admin ejs file while starting chat i use to emit that data to user after data save with in database while sending data from admin to server.In admin ejs file i have also defined script file for socket chat.But while using socket.emit with data from admin to user it shows socket undefined.

App.js code:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app); 
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit("message_to_client",{ message: "Welcome to the chat", name: "Server", "isAdminOnline" : (adminXMPP.length > 0)
    });
```

Controller code for admin:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

      var senderid=$('#sender').val();
      var msgdes=$('#btn-input').val();
      var receiverid=$('#userid').val();
      //alert(msgdes);
        e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/savechat?senderid="+senderid+"&receiverid="+receiverid+"&msg="+msgdes,
      success: function(data){
        $('#btn-input').val('');

        socket.emit("chat",data);

    }
    });
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `io` on the client instead of `socket`. From [here](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/).

Comment: i have implemented your your answer with in my code still getting issue with in controller while passing io.emit from admin to user

Comment: Even though i have tried your answer by declaring socket as const and instead of io i have used socket  iam getting same error  socket undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Inialize socket with the request URLs

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost:5000/dashboard');
</script>
```